# Translation for TYPO3 Backend Content Elements

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-10.x

How can I get a translation string in TYPO3 Backend?

In language overview in Backend, I have my custom Content Elements displayed.
If there is no link title set, the button has a language specific default value:

- EN: Read more
- DE: Mehr erfahren

In Frontend, we have `<f:translate`, but in Backend this does not work?

Version: TYPO3 V10 LTS

Answer (score 0):

depending on where your label is. the string is defined in TCA (Table Configuration Array) or Flexform. in both cases you use an LLL reference instead of the label

usually somthing like this:

`LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/backend.xlf:my_label_name`

let me pick explain the diffrent parts:

**LLL:** proccess this aht Local Language resource (similar to http: in an URL)

**EXT:** this is an Extension Path chheck prefixes like typo3conf/ext/ or typo3/sysext

**my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/backend.xlf** the path to the file

**:my_label_name** the label inside the file

Comment: We have customized Backend Layouts for content Elements. So what I need is Fluid Syntax (f:translate does not work in backend). 
Another option is PHP for loading the language key, as we have preloading code for the content elements in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`<f:translate>` does work in the backend as well.

The language file should at least look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2013-08-22T11:22:55Z" product-name="efemtpy">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="title">
                <source>Title</source>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Maybe you forgot the `<source>`-Tag like I did before.